# How can I update pivot table on laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, pivot-table, eloquent

I use laravel 5.3

I have 3 table : table product, table category and table products_categories

table product : id, name, etc

table category : id, name, etc

table products_categories : id, product_id, category_id

In model product, I have method this :

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'products_categories', 'product_id', 'category_id')
                ->withPivot('id')
                ->withTimestamps();
}
```

So 1 product have many category

My code like this

For example $param['category'] like this :

> Array (
>       ['category1'] => 4
>       ['category2'] => 11
>       ['category3'] => 18 )
>
> $product_id = 1

```
foreach ($param['category'] as $category) {
    Product::find($product_id)
        ->categories()
        ->attach(
            $category, 
            []
        );
}
```

It used to add category on the pivot table and it works

But if I update category on the pivot table, it does not work

I try like this :

For example the category previously edited like this

$param['category'] =

> Array (
>       ['category1'] => 5
>       ['category2'] => 12
>       ['category3'] => 19 )
>
> $product_id = 1

And the code to update data on the pivot table like this :

```
foreach ($param['category'] as $category) {
    Product::find($product_id)
           ->categories()
           ->wherePivot('product_id', $product_id)
           ->updateExistingPivot($category, ['category_id' => $category]);
}
```

It did not update the field category successfully

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use the [`sync()` function](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#syncing-associations)

```
Product::find($product_id)->categories()->sync($array_of_categories_id)
```

Comment: @Gabriel Caruso, Your answer seems correct. It seems that it also does not use loops. I will make sure again. Btw, I want to ask. How do you think my code to add data. I use a loop to add category. Does it need not use loop?

Comment: @Amit Gupta, Yes, seems the answer correct. But I will make sure again. Btw, How do you think my code to add data? Is that true? I use loop to add it

Comment: Loop is not always the best way. Image that your product has 1.000 categories, 1.000 loops? No! Database (like MySQL) alows you to [batch insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526917/how-to-do-a-batch-insert-in-mysql), and the `sync()` function uses this!

Comment: You don't need to use loop here.

Comment: @Gabriel Caruso, I am confused if not using a loop. How can I get the category? Maybe you can update your answer. So besides exist code for update category, there is also exist code to add category

Comment: @Amit Gupta,  I am confused if not using a loop. How can I get the category?

Comment: @TrendingNews to access your categories by a product, just use the [many to many relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) like `$product->categories()->get()`, and here you can loop. But, to add and update your relationship, just use the `sync()` method

Comment: @Gabriel Caruso, Great. I use this : `Product::find($product_id)->categories()->sync($param['category']);` to add and update category, it works. Thanks a lot

Comment: @TrendingNews Glad I could help. If you can, mark this answer as the correct one, I'd appreciate that :)

Comment: @Gabriel Caruso, Okay. I will give you answer. But I want ask one last question. This is about delete category on the table pivot. I try like this : `Product::find($product_id)->categories()->where('product_id', $product_id)->delete();`. But it does not works. There exist error : `Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails`. How can I delete category correctly?

Comment: @TrendingNews This is a security reason. Use the `detach()` method from the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships), and should work.
Ex: `Product::find($product_id)->categories()->where('product_id'‌​, $product_id)->detach();` to remove all relations and then `Product::find($product_id)->categories()->where('product_id'‌​, $product_id)->delete();`

Comment: @Gabriel Caruso, There exist error. This code : `->where('product_id'‌​‌​, $product_id)`. That's what caused the error. There seems to be a misplaced or wrong field call

Comment: @TrendingNews Wow, not seen that coming. Please, chat me and I’ll try to help you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146555/discussion-between-trending-news-and-gabriel-caruso).

Comment: @Gabriel Caruso, Like this : `Product::find($id)->categories()->detach();`, it works

Comment: @Gabriel Caruso, I need you help. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45231810/how-can-i-use-db-transaction-in-laravel